# Removing lines from a hash in Perl to a new file, if value meets certain requirements

Tags: perl, hash

Perl newbie, could use some help. Using a hash in Perl, trying to remove a line from the original file into a new file, if the value is less than or equal to 20.

So original file:

```
apple       30
orange      45
pear        2
```

Resulting two files would be:

```
apple       30
orange      45

pear        2
```

This is my code so far:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

open (INFILE1, 'sample.txt') or die "Cannot open INFILE1: $!\n";
open (OUTFILE, '>output.txt') or die "Cannot open OUTFILE: $!\n";

my %Hash;

while(<INFILE1>){
   chomp;
   my ($k, $v) = split(/\s+/);
   push @{$Hash{'INFILE1'}{$k}},$v;
}
```

I think I have to use a foreach loop next, but I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: Please format your sample input and code by indenting it with four spaces and putting newline before the block.

Comment: Why do you need hash if you can just print/not print string to output file right away, depending on your condition?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need hash for this task, as you are not comparing values of different keys. To read all lines from a file you can use `while (my $line = <$in_fh>)`. Additionally, using bareword filehandle names is discouraged, use scalar instead: `open (my $in_fh, 'sample.txt') ...`. Putting it all together:

```
open (my $in_fh, 'sample.txt') or die "Cannot open INFILE1: $!\n";
open (my $out_fh, '>output.txt') or die "Cannot open OUTFILE: $!\n";

while (my $line = <$in_fh>)
{
    chomp $line;
    my ($k, $v) = split /\s+/, $line;

    if ($v > 20)
    {
        print $out_fh $line . "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ perl -wane 'print if $F[1] <= 20' input.txt > output.txt
```

The `-w` switch turns on warnings.

The `-n` switch creates a `while (<>) { ... }` loop around the program.

The `-a` switch turns on autosplit mode, which splits `$_` into `@F` for each line.

The `-e` switch specifies our short little filter program.

Comment: The OP also wants to delete matches from the input file.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot If/when the OP clarifies the question, I will certainly update my answer.